# Add space between IconButton inside actionIcons in MUI ImageListItemBar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I appreciate if anyone can give a solution to add space between or space evenly between the two IconButton inside the ImageListItem in Material UI. The code uses Material UI library inside Reactjs

```
<ImageListItem
        key={item?.id}
        cols={item.cols || 1}
        rows={item.rows || 1}
      >
        <img
          {...srcSetStyle(item.url, 121, item.rows, item.cols)}
          alt={item.url}
          loading="lazy"
        />
        <ImageListItemBar
          sx={{
            background: "transparent",
            top: "5%",
          }}
          position="top"
          actionPosition="left"
          actionIcon={
            <>
              <IconButton
                sx={{ color: "red" }}
              >
                {item.isFavorite ? (
                  <FavoriteIcon className="favoriteIcon" />
                ) : (
                  <FavoriteBorderIcon
                    className="favoriteIcon"
                  />
                )}
              </IconButton>

              <IconButton
                className="addIcon"
                sx={{
                  color: "red",
                }}
              >
                <AddCircleOutlineIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </>
          }
        />
      </ImageListItem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change flex-grow attributes of both `MuiImageListItemBar-titleWrap` and `MuiImageListItemBar-actionIcon` classes of `ImageListItemBar` like this:

```
sx={{
    background: "transparent",
    top: "5%",
    "& .MuiImageListItemBar-titleWrap": {
      flexGrow: 0
    },
    "& .MuiImageListItemBar-actionIcon": {
      flexGrow: 1
    }
}}
```

After that, you need to wrap your icons with a div and add desired style like this:

```
<div
  style={{
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between"
  }}
>
    ... (action button icons here)
</div>
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-image-list-6z6xy8?file=/demo.tsx) for a live working example of this solution.